# Transferring variables between two classes

Tags: android

I have 2 classes:

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView
public class TouchImageViewActivity extends Activity
```

In my `TouchImageView` class I have touch listener that calculates where you have touched the image. What I need is to transfer the touch point to the `TouchImageViewActivity` without creating new instance of it. The touch calculated constancy.

Calling `TouchImageView` from `TouchImageViewActivity`:

```
TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.g_map2048);
```

Comment: You could move the listener to the activity.

Comment: Tried that, not worked very well

Comment: Is there a reason wh you cannot just call a member of TouchImageViewActivity from the listener? like my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare an `interface` inside `TouchImageView` and make `TouchImageViewActivity` **implements** that interface..
Then when you finish your calculations call `interface.method`..this will call the method in the activity...

Your interface:

```
public interface OnCalculationsCompleted{
    public void onCalculationsCompleted(values);
}
```

TouchImageViewActivity :

```
public TouchImageViewActivity implements OnCalculationsCompleted{
    public void onCalculationsCompleted(values){}
}
```

Comment: The thing is that i need the data while calculations running.

Comment: @user1891408 meaning you have a thread in TouchImageViewActivity doing calculations continiously? or some service?

Comment: I have thread in TouchImageView that doing calculations continiously, that I need them int TouchImageViewActivity also continiously

Answer (score 1):

I think I got your confusion :) It looks like:

```
TouchImageView
```

Is already nested in your TouchImageViewActivity.  You don't need to "transfer" the touchpoint, simply create a method inside TouchImageViewActivity with whatever you want to do with that data, and call it from the listener you set in TouchImageView